# Class 'yii\app\models\DB' not found in yii2

Tags: database, model, yii2

I am trying to use database connection inside my model but it was not getting connected throwing error as "Class 'app\models\DB' not found". I have created a common model to be extended by all my models inside modules that means all models extends the CommonModel, I am getting this error inside the CommonModel. I have read yii documentation regards database connection & googled for the same but I din't find any solution. My code is:

models\CommonModel.php

```
namespace app\models;
use Yii;
use yii\base\NotSupportedException;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\helpers\Security;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;
use yii\db\Query;
use app\models\Mailsettings;
use \PDO as PDO;
class CommonModel extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord{
  protected $_db;
  protected $_sql;
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->_db = DB::init();  // This line causing the error
    $pdo = Timetrackdb::getPdoConnection(); 
  }
  ----
  ----
}
```

config/db.php & config/db2.php

```
return [
  'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
  'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db_name',
  'username' => 'db_username',
  'password' => 'db_password',
  'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```

config/web.php

```
$db = require __DIR__ . '/db.php';
$db2 = require __DIR__ . '/db2.php';
$config = [
  'id' => 'basic',
  'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
  'bootstrap' => ['log'],
  'modules' => [
     'my_module1' => [
        'class' => 'app\modules\my_module1'
     ],
     'my_module2' => [
        'class' => 'app\modules\my_module2'
     ],
   ],
  ------
  ------
  'db' => $db,
  'db2' => $db2,
  ------
  ------
];
```

I have created 2 modules in which one module is working fine with the same type of database connection but the other module's db connection is not working properly. Can anyone please tell whats wrong with this code? Thanks.

Comment: The line you pointed tells that you want to use `DB` class under the same namespace as `CommonModel` and call its method `init()` and apparently there is no class like that. Is this the case?

Comment: yes, I hope you understood my problem, as I said my module-2 uses the db connection in the same way it works fine but in module-1 getting this issue. FYI, I am a beginner to Yii framework.

Comment: But this is a matter of understanding how namespaces works and where exactly is this `DB` class of yours. Please read [PHP namespaces docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) and maybe [PSR-4 specification](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)

Comment: yes bro I know about the namespaces business and I tried to include the 'DB' class in that file using "use app\models\DB" but din't fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yii deals with connecting to databases for you, you don't need `PDO`. Just access `Yii::$app->db2` if you want to have `CommonModel` or derived ActiveRecord classes to use the second database as their data store:

```
class CommonModel extends ActiveRecord {
    public static function getDb()
    {
        // this will cause Yii to use the database configured as 'db2' in config/web.php
        return Yii::$app->db2;
    }
}

class Car extends CommonModel { }
// will try to insert a new row in `db2`.`car`
(new Car)->save();
```

You may also need to do the following if you're going to perform cross-schema queries (`config/db2.php`):

```
return [
  // ...
  // add and adjust the keys below
  'tablePrefix' => '',
  'schemaMap' => [
      'mysql' => [
          'class' => 'yii\db\mysql\Schema',
          'defaultSchema' => 'my_db_name',
      ],
  ],
];
```

Comment: Thanks @haveyaseen, That solved the issue but I have already solved it in a different way but **to test your answer I still tried your solution and it is also worked**.